# C#: count and get Id of rows from sql

Tags: c#, sql

what's wrong pls?

I can get number of records but can't get id value of each record

I have this function to count and get id values:
I think the issue is in the function

form1

```
 public List<int> countInTable(Double codebar)
        {
            cmd.Connection = cn; // sqlconn 
            cn.Open();
            List<int> id = new List<int>();        
            String countString = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM  medicaments WHERE code_bare =  @codebar  ";
            var myCommand = new SqlCommand(countString, cn);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codebar", codebar);
            int count = Convert.ToInt32(myCommand.ExecuteScalar());
            id.Add(count);
            using (rd = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // loop over all rows returned by SqlDataReader
                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    // grab the column no. 0 (id" from 
                    // SQL select statement) as a string then int, and store it into list of id
                    t0 = rd[0].ToString();
                    id.Add(int.Parse(t0));
                }
            }
            rd.Close();
            cn.Close();
            return  id;
        }
```

Then i call the first function in another form to get data of each record
form2

```
 private void laodProduct(Double codebar)
        {
           this.listView2.Items.Clear();
           List<int> total = manipBaseDonnees.countInTable(double.Parse(textBox2.Text));
           foreach (int t in total)
           {
               listBox1.Items.Add(t);
               List<string> donnees = manipBaseDonnees.getFromTableID(t);
               var item1 = new ListViewItem(new[] { donnees[1], donnees[2], donnees[6], donnees[7], donnees[8], donnees[4], donnees[0] }, -1, Color.Empty, Color.Yellow, null);
               this.listView2.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { item1 });
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is a count query, you cannot use the same query to get each entry. You need to use a second query for that:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM  medicaments WHERE code_bare =  @codebar";
```

If you only want the ID field, then only include that in your query:

```
string query = "SELECT ID FROM  medicaments WHERE code_bare =  @codebar";
```

In addition, if you are just going to iterate over all the results anyway, you might as well just drop he count query and count the results of `ExecuteReader` as you loop over them.

Comment: What about count variable? He needs to change that as well

Comment: @Kuzgun: Yeah, I said a second query... not change the current query

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your function but with the way you select data, you use aggregate function COUNT(*) and this returns only row count if you add  MAX(ID) this will do same think as if you would've grouped your data by ID what is wrong with is is that in that case you will get two columns one will be ID value and the second one would've been COUNT but it would be the same for all the ID's

```
String countString = "SELECT MAX(ID), COUNT (*) FROM  medicaments WHERE code_bare =  @codebar  ";
```

Answer (score 0):

oh yes Thanks, I copied the string from my first function without giving attention

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM  medicaments WHERE code_bare =  @codebar";
```